# Не загружается фото в VK через VK API

Tags: ios, swift, vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь загрузить фотографию в VK через их же api. Вот мой код:

```
        let image = UIImage(named: "vk")!
        let data = image.pngData()!

        let site = URL(string: "https://pu.vk.com/c****/upload.php?*****....")! //<= Ссылка для загрузки фотографий в альбом

        upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "imagefile", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }, to: site) { (encodingResult) in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let uploadRequest, let streamingFromDisk, let streamFileURL):
                print("success")
                print(uploadRequest)

                uploadRequest.validate().responseJSON() { responseJSON in
                    switch responseJSON.result {
                    case .success(let value):
                        print(value)

                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                    }
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

В консоль выводится ответ:

```
{
    aid = ******;
    hash = ******;
    "photos_list" = "[]";
    server = *****;
}
```

photo_list пустой, хотя в нем должна быть информация, для последующего сохранения изображения изображения в альбоме VK. Подскажите, что я делаю не правильно?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен. Необходимо называть фотографии следующим образом file1,file2...file5(5 максимум). Вот исправление

```
upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "file1", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }, to: site)
```